# JMETER not Recording

Tags: jmeter

I'm new to jmeter
I'm trying to record asp.net application
While recording logged in to application successfully, after that travelling to next page (which is expected).
In the next page after filling up the form clicking Generate button
the page is getting reloaded instead of travelling to other page.

Comment: This is very confusing to follow. Can you pretend that we have no idea what idea you are talking about and then explain your problem.

Comment: I mean to say, I'm recording .net application using JMETER. After giving port number and adjusting proxy settings I clicked start recording. First comes the login page. That is recorded successfully. Next page comes with the form like name, age, gender, DOB, etc., after entering those details I clicked "OK" button. At this point of time instead of getting success page, the page is getting reloaded. Can you please give the solution for this ??

Comment: any feedback on my answer ? if it was helpful it should be accepted and possibly upvoted so that it's helpful to others

Answer (score 0):

In Test script recorder switch http implementation to Java and try again.

Ensure you use last jmeter version.